# Não consigo importar uma classe DriverManagerDataSource no maven Java Web

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, maven

````
```
package com.eventsApp;



import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


@Configuration
public class DataConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eventosapp");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("Summer1945.");
        return dataSource;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter(){
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        adapter.setShowSql(true);
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        adapter.setPrepareConnection(true);
        return adapter;
    }
    
    
}
```

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eventosapp");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("Summer1945.");
        return dataSource;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter(){
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        adapter.setShowSql(true);
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        adapter.setPrepareConnection(true);
        return adapter;
    }
````

Estava assistindo uma vídeo aula de Spring Boot da Michelli Brito e tive um problema ao importar está classe `DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();`
Ele não me da a opção de importá-la, já vi na documentação e não entendi muito bem o que quer dizer, agradeço toda ajuda !

Detalhe estou usando o Eclipse !

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Pelo erro que você está tendo ao importar a classe `DriverManagerDataSource`, provavelmente você precisa importar a biblioteca do Spring que contém essa classe. Para isso, você pode adicionar a dependência no arquivo `pom.xml` do seu projeto, caso esteja usando Maven, ou no arquivo `build.gradle`, caso esteja usando Gradle.

Para o Maven, adicione as seguintes linhas dentro da tag dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.14</version>
</dependency>
```

Para o Gradle, adicione a seguinte linha dentro de `dependencies`:

```
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.3.14'
```

Após adicionar a dependência, salve o arquivo e atualize as dependências do projeto. Se estiver usando o Eclipse com o Maven, clique com o botão direito no projeto, selecione Maven e depois Update Project. Se estiver usando o Gradle, abra um terminal e execute o comando `./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies`.

Depois de atualizar as dependências, tente importar a classe `DriverManagerDataSource` novamente. O Eclipse deverá exibir a opção de importação agora.

> EDITADO

**Responderei a baixo referente a outra duvida que notei você ter perguntado,**

O erro na linha do `HibernateJpaVendorAdapter` pode estar ocorrendo porque a classe não está sendo importada corretamente. Você pode tentar adicionar o import na classe.

`import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;`

Quanto ao arquivo XML, não é necessário para usar o Hibernate com Spring Boot. A configuração é feita por meio das anotações `@EnableJpaRepositories` e `@EntityScan` em uma classe de configuração, como a `DataConfiguration` que você compartilhou. Espero que isso ajude!

Comment: Cara vlw, deu pra importar certinho !!, foi mal não ter cido bem claro era no maven mesmo

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, fico feliz em te-lo ajudado! E caso tenha dificuldades com um erro na linha do `HibernateJpaVendorAdapter` pode estar ocorrendo porque a classe não está sendo importada corretamente. Você pode tentar adicionar o import na classe: "`import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;`". Quanto ao arquivo XML, não é necessário para usar o Hibernate com Spring Boot. A configuração é feita por meio das anotações `@EnableJpaRepositories` e `@EntityScan` em uma classe de configuração, como a `DataConfiguration` que você compartilhou. Espero que isso ajude!